# self mapping one to many hibernate spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, junit, hibernate-mapping

MYSQL Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `nodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `node_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(255),
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `node_id_self_to_id` (`node_id`),
  KEY `type_foreign_to_node_types` (`type`),
  CONSTRAINT `node_id_self_to_id` FOREIGN KEY (`node_id`) REFERENCES `nodes` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `type_foreign_to_node_types` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `node_types` (`id`)
)
```

MY Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nodes")
public class Nodes {
@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "node_id")
private int id;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="node_id")
private Nodes nodeId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="nodeId")
private Set<Nodes> mynodeIds = new HashSet<Nodes>();

private String name;
private Date created_at;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "type")
private Nodetypes nodetypes;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "nodes", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Nodeattributes> nodeattributes;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "nodes", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Products> products;


public Nodetypes getNodetypes() {
    return nodetypes;
}

public void setNodetypes(Nodetypes nodetypes) {
    this.nodetypes = nodetypes;
}

public Set<Products> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(Set<Products> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

public Set<Nodeattributes> getNodeattributes() {
    return nodeattributes;
}

public void setNodeattributes(Set<Nodeattributes> nodeattributes) {
    this.nodeattributes = nodeattributes;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Date getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}

public void setCreated_at(Date created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}
}
```

and In the Junit test,

```
public void testCreateNodes() {
    Nodes node1 = new Nodes();
    node1.setId(2222);
    node1.setCreated_at(new java.util.Date());
    node1.setName("nodeName");
    node1.setNodetypes(nodetypesRepository.findById(1111).get());
    nodesRepository.save(node1);
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot Project. How to do a self mapping of One To Many  in Hibernate. So, How can I Implement hibernate self join annotations one to many? Any help would be appreciated. I have followed this blog to develop the project, but still getting null value in my MYSQL.

https://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/

Comment: What are the exceptions? Include them in the question

Comment: done. please look at it now

Comment: I still don't see stacktraces. I saw in an edit `Could not extract resultset` that can have many reasons. Provide the full stacktrace

Comment: I'm just getting a null now, please copy the entity class

Comment: For which field you get the null?

Comment: for the foreign key, node_id

Comment: `@JoinColumn(name = "node_id")` on `private int id;` is definitly wrong. Also I asked for the field, not the column

Comment: `private Nodes nodeId`

Comment: In your unit test you never call set a value to `nodeId`. In fact, you dont even have a method to do so. Why do you think a value should be written to `nodeId`, if you never set a value to it?

Comment: `node1.set(node1);`  is this correct?

Comment: As of now you have no method like `set(Nodes node)`. An autogenerated method would be like `public void setNodeId(Nodes nodeId){this.nodeId = nodeId}`